# Adding dynamic property to a python object

Tags: python, dynamic, properties, addition

```
site = object()
mydict = {'name': 'My Site', 'location': 'Zhengjiang'}
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    setattr(site, key, value)
print site.a  # it doesn't work
```

The above code didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: it would be helpful when you say something doesn't work, to give a bit more information like what you wanted to happen, and/or any exceptions thrown, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to populate one `dict` with another is [the `update()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update), so if you extend `object` to ensure your object has a `__dict__` you could try something like this:

```
>>> class Site(object):
...     pass
...
>>> site = Site()
>>> site.__dict__.update(dict)
>>> site.a
```

Or possibly even:

```
>>> class Site(object):
...     def __init__(self,dict):
...         self.__dict__.update(dict)
...
>>> site = Site(dict)
>>> site.a
```

Answer (score 5):

[As docs say](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#object), `object()` returns featureless object, meaning it cannot have any attributes. It doesn't have `__dict__`.

What you could do is the following:

```
>>> site = type('A', (object,), {'a': 42})
>>> site.a
42
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class site(object):
    pass
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    setattr(site,k,v)
print site.a #it does works
```

Comment: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Comment: your solution may end up being more confusing to the original poster.  In their original code, they want to add attributes to an object which is an instance of `object`.  However, you offer a solution which adds attributes to the class `site`.  I recognize that it works, but may not be what they had in mind.

Comment: accepted solution does the same, as adding an attribute to an `object` instance is not possible